# Flutter RefreshIndicator for bottom scrolling

Tags: flutter, refresh

I have a `ListView` of items. I want to indicate to the user about loading more items, on reaching the end of the list.

Does `RefreshIndicator` support a bottom-scrolling indication?

If not, is there any alternative?

Comment: May be this one helps https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll

Comment: Yes I can see there are other alternatives such as https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh and https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator

Comment: But it's a bit strange that `RefreshIndicator` does not support this functionality

Comment: RefreshIndicator is to reload data with same data, use https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_listview

Comment: The only difference between loading and refreshing is where the indicator appears. Both are doing exactly the same, waiting for async functionality while showing a progress indication. It's a bit bothering that it does not support a bottom indication.